# Powershell move multiple files to multiple directories

Tags: powershell

I have problems with my script. My goals is move files from multiple directories to multiple targets using LastWriteTime. When I run my script I get error code:

```
Move-Item : Cannot find path 'W:\files\cv\data\test.csv' because it does not exist.
At line:28 char:13
+             Move-Item -Path "$($checkThis.Source)$($file.Name)" -Dest ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (W:\files\cv\data\test.csv:String) [Move-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

Script:

```
function Write-Log($str) {
  Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value "$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") $str"
}

$logpath = "C:\temp\Logs\"
$logFilePath = $logpath + "\test_files" + $(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd") + ".log"

$checkThese = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{Id='first'; Source='W:\files\cv\data'; Target="D:\files\archive\cv\Data\"}
    [pscustomobject]@{Id='second'; Source='W:\files\tv\data'; Target="D:\files\archive\tv\Data\"}
)   
#Move files from source dir to archive after this many days since last write
$archiveAfterDays = 1*1

Write-Log "[BEGIN]"

ForEach($checkThis in $checkThese) {
    Write-Log "[INFO] Process $($checkThis.Id) archive"
    Write-Log "[INFO] Start archive"
    Write-Log "[INFO] Check folder $($checkThis.Source) for files to archive"
    }
        #Archive files older than $archiveAfterDays
        $files = Get-ChildItem $checkThis.Source | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$archiveAfterDays)}
        ForEach ($file in $files)
        {
 
            
            Move-Item -Path "$($checkThis.Source)$($file.Name)" -Destination "$($checkThis.Target)$subfolder$($file.Name)" -Force
        }

        Write-Log "[END]"
```

Comment: Problem solved:<

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
    ForEach($checkThis in $checkThese) {
    Write-Log "[INFO] Process $($checkThis.Id) Copy files to monthly DB"
    Write-Log "[INFO] Start copy"
    Write-Log "[INFO] Check folder $($checkThis.Source) for files to move"


    $files = Get-ChildItem $checkThis.Source | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)}
    ForEach ($file in $files) {
        Copy-Item -Path "$($checkThis.Source)\$($file.Name)" -Destination "$($checkThis.Target)\$($file.Name)" -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).